# AI - what is included in the state

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I'm taking my first course in AI, and I have to define some problems in my homework (not yet solve them, just supply a definition). 
So I have to define about [boolean satisfiability problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem)
:

1. What is a state?
2. What is the initial state?
3. What is a final state?
4. What are the operators?

My question is: Should the formula be a part of the state?

Considerations so far:

- The operator doesn't change it, and it's constant through the computation, so it's not.
- If I do include it, in theory, the search space gets much bigger, since more states are possible, but in reality the formula can't be changed, so I get a big state, and a branching factor that is not corresponding.
- It's varying from one execution to the next, so it should be a part of the state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need only really consider the varying parts of the problem to be a state when conducting a search such as this, although I'd say in this case it really comes down to how you define the problem.

The search space for a given run of the algorithm depends upon the input formula, but after that is fixed, ie you are searching the space of n length bit vectors where n is the number of variables in the formula. So the formula is not part of the state because it does not vary.

The counter claim is that you are searching in a larger space of formula-vector pairs, but as you cannot change the formula as part of the problem, this has not really increased the size of the search space. So I would not make the claim that "If I do include it, in theory the search space gets much bigger". It does not, the reachable states are the same, the branching is the same, the space that requires exploring to solve the problem is the same.

Given this, my answer would that the formula is not part of the state, but defines the nature of the state space. So the answers to your four questions will each be functionally dependant on the formula in some way, but the state depends only on the length of the formula.

Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

### This is just a note for future readers - Not an answer

Vic Smith is right, another way to look at the fact that `in theory there are more states` but in practice not (my second dot), is just to think about it as separate bondage spaces. For example for the formula `X or Y` there is one bondage space, and for `not X and Y` there is another one and they have no common nodes in the representation.

So it can vary from one execution to another, but still has the same "reachable" states, and same branching factor. And each execution has a different starting state.